# Are there efficient black-box constructions of sigma-protocols for SAT?

Tags: cr.crypto-security, communication-complexity, zero-knowledge, black-box

> Is there a known *black-box* construction for the following implication?
>   
>   non-interactive string commitment that stretches additively by an
>   
>   amount which does not depend on the string being committed to
>   
> $\implies$
>   [sigma-protocol](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~ivan/Sigma.pdf#page=3) for, equivalently, [circuit-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_satisfiability) or [3-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#3-satisfiability), whose communication
>   
>   complexity scales subquadratically with the size of the SAT instance

The only methods I know either

use circuit-SAT, commit to the values of enough gates, and then use the *code* of the commitment scheme to prove that the values committed to are correct and cause

the circuit to output TRUE $\:$ (using the code makes the construction not black box)

or

use a graph with a number of edges that scales linearly with the number of variables

(as the case may be) and commit to each entry in the adjacency matrix, for a

communication complexity that scales quadratically with the size of the SAT instance

or

reduce to 3-coloring and, although the communication for each instance of the "core"

only scales linearly, need a number of parallel executions of the "core" that scales linearly,

for a communication complexity that scales quadratically with the size of the SAT instance

.